# pandas update specific row with nan values

Tags: pandas, replace, row, nan, fillna

I've been browsing around but I cannot find the answer to my particular question.

I have a Dataframe with hundreds of columns and hundreds of rows. I want to change the occurring NaN values only for the first row and replace them with an empty string. This has been answered for changing a column or an entire dataframe, but not a particular row. I also don't want to modify the NaNs occurring in other rows.

I've tried the following:

```
dataframe.loc[0].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

and I also tried with:

```
dataframe.update(dataframe.loc[0].fillna(''))
```

but when I call the dataframe, it is not modified. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the data frame `df`

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([1, np.nan], size=(4, 4)),
    list('WXYZ'), list('ABCD')
)

df

     A    B    C    D
W  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
X  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
Y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Z  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

---

If we use a non-scalar, namely an array like thing to select the first row, we'll get a `pd.DataFrame` object back and can conveniently `fillna` and pass to `pd.DataFrame.update`

```
df.update(df.iloc[[0]].fillna(''))
df

     A    B    C    D
W  1.0       1.0     
X  1.0    1  NaN    1
Y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Z  1.0  NaN  NaN    1
```

Notice that I use `[0]` instead of `0` within the `iloc`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This works perfectly. Why will changing loc to iloc work? my index name is also 0, so I thought using loc[0] was the same as iloc[0]

Comment: `iloc[0]` says to take the first row by position.  `loc[0]` says take the row labeled `0` which may or may not be the first row.